# Using Enmet with ERB

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

I'm wondering if it is possible to easily mark up ERB templates using the Enmet/ZenCoding plugin for SublimeText2.

For example, you can normally do:

`span.goodbye{hi there!}` --> tab --> `<span class="goodbye">hi there!</span>`

Is there a way to do something like:

`span.goodbye{<%= @post.content%>}` --> tab --> `<span class="goodbye"><%= @post.content %></span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `span.goodbye{<%= @post.content%>}` works as required.

But I suggest you to [create a custom snippet](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/), something like `"erb": "<%= |${child} %>"` so you can write abbreviations like this:

`span.goodbye>erb{@post.content}`